# Play Live Stream using cloudfront

Tags: amazon-s3, video-streaming, amazon-cloudfront, rtmp, live-streaming

I am running `nginx rtmp module` on `ec2-instance` and also, have mounted `s3` with the help of `goofys(/var/mounted-s3-dir)` on the ec2-instance.

Below is the nginx config of my server.

```
rtmp {
    server {
        listen 1935;

        application live {
            live on;
            dash on;
            dash_path /var/mounted-s3-dir;
        }
    }
}
```

> I am able to `play the dash stream` through s3 via cloudfront. I want to
>   push the `rtmp stream to s3` and `play rtmp stream via cloudfront`. Could you assist me to achieve this.

Comment: Did you get the way to upload on S3 and and cloud front.